# Mysql select list of items (repeat until certain amount)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure:

```
Table: products

id, name, sort_order
```

Let's say I only have 5 products, but I want 20.

How would I loop through to get 20 results?

Additionally, I'll need to start at a specific sort_order.  So let's say I have

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

and I want to get 20 results and start at 3.  It should end up as:

```
3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,etc.
```

Any ideas? I'm totally lost.. thank you!

Comment: What language are you accessing mySQL with? What do you mean by "loop through"? mySQL is a database, not a programming language, so it has very little to offer in terms of control structures.

Comment: You won't achieve this in a MySQL query, at least a single one. You could, however, retrieve all 5 products from the DB, store them in an associative array and treat the array to produce the result you're after.

Comment: So you want to *fake* 20 results even though you only have 5 records?

Comment: i disagree with you ben. MySQL is pretty mighty if you know how to handle stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$how_many = 20;
$counter = 0;
$rows = array();

$result = mysql_query("Your query");
while($row == mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

$expanded = array();
for($i = 0; $counter < $how_many; $counter++) {
  $expanded[] = $rows[$i];
  $i++;
  if($i == count($rows)) {
    $i = 0;
  }
}
```

And now `$expanded` is filled with those 5 rows for 4 times.

Edit: and don't forget to adjust `$i` to your start element. For your example that would mean `$i = 2` (third element).

Comment: I used this basic idea.. but mine is a little different... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create a table named abc and use this procedure to populate the table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `populator`(i INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE existing int;
   DECLARE counting int;
   DECLARE limitation int default i;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO existing FROM asd;
   theLoop: LOOP
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counting FROM abc;
     IF (existing + counting) >  i
       THEN SET limitation = i - counting;
     END IF;
     IF counting >= i
       THEN LEAVE theLoop;
       ELSE
         SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO abc SELECT id from asd LIMIT ", limitation);
         PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
         EXECUTE s1;
         DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
     END IF;
   END LOOP theLoop;
END
```

remember to rename the tables. i used `asd` as source table and `abc` as destination table. if you do the concatenation thing right you can even write a procedure that works with temporary tables.

Comment: but be carefull. do not try this with an empty source table!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in MySQL by cheating:

```
SELECT
   t1.id
FROM
   products t1
   CROSS JOIN products t2
LIMIT
   2, 20
```

Like the others, I'm not 100% sure what you want.  You want to show the same products over again until 20 times?